# visual studio 2017 won't let me sign in

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I am trying to sign in to my VSO through VS 2017, but it keeps asking me for my password every time I press enter. After about 6 goes it shows;
[image: Visual studio message]

> Sorry we ran into a problem. An error has occurred and we can no longer retrieve information for your account. Please re-enter your credentials.

I have an office 365 account and, had, changed the primary address earlier but I have put this back now. I have tried both email address I had used in there. When I enter the wrong password in it shows the incorrect password message, I even changed the password through visual studio and that worked too.

I can login to VSO ok through the browser but it won't let me through VS.

[image]

Comment: Can you sign into VisualStudio.com with those credentials?

Comment: Hi Ken, yes i can no problem. just not connect to the project through VS.

Comment: Do you have a proxy server?

Comment: No just a straight connection it was working fine until yesterday when I tried to check in my code.

Comment: @AidanBromley  
What's your email address domain? And are you (the email address) the owner of the VSTS account or a member of the VSTS account? How did you sign in in VS, did you log in through team explorer -> manage connections?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT please see the updated screen shot, I am the owner of the VSTS and yes i am trying to login through the Team explorer> managed connections.

Comment: Have you gone into the Windows Credential Manager and deleted the entries for your account? That should force a reprompt and should cancel out the current credential metadata.

Comment: @jessehouwing thank you for your reply, i have tried this and even removed the account in the register product but still won't work.

Comment: I have setup a new user in VSTS and made that the admin i can now login with that account no problem, I have deleted the old user and tryied to re add them in but still the same problem.

Comment: Probably the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52261546/2441442

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to not having permissions to access a private Nuget feed.