# How do I connect to my Teamproject, after I changed my primary Account Alias?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

A few days ago I changed my primarly alias for my Microsoft Account. Now I want to checkin my code, and get some error messages:

> An attempt to communicate with Visual Studio Team Services failed because a token could not be retrieved.
>
> You are anot authorized to access [...]

Here is a picture of it:

[image: Picture of the error messages]

As suggested, I already tried re-entering my credentials. But this has no effect. I already tried closing Visual Studio, restarted my PC, but nothing helps.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by deleting the following folder after I have closed Visual Studio:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService
```

Then I opened Visual Studio again, and clicked Manage Connections:

[image: Picture of Manage Connections]

Finaly I have connected again to my Microsoft Account, restarted Visual Studio and was able to check in my code.

Comment: Self answers can not be accepted within the first 2 days @AndyLi-MSFT

Comment: to get to the mentioned folder, paste %LOCALAPPDATA% into windows search field

Comment: or paste above string into `win + r`

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the hidden .vs folder within the solutions directory resolved the problem.